# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated error in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I am trying to run a code that contains this function and I am getting the "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated".

```
void Lapenta_Markidis( long double v[3], long double E[3], long double B[3], long double c2,  long double upart[3] ){
   
   long double   upartk[3], vbar[3];
   long double  tmp[3], Fk[3], C1[3], C2[3] ;
   long double  dupartk[3];
   long double gL = gamma_v(v, c2);
   

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){       
        upart[i] = v[i]*gL;       // momentum at start of time step
        upartk[i] = upart[i];
    }


    /* Start of the nonlinear cycle */

    long double     abserr = 1.0;
    long double     tol=1e-14;
    int             nkmax=10;
    int             nk = 0; //


    do{
        long double  J11, J12, J13,J21, J22,  J23, J31, J32, J33, Det;
        long double  iJ11, iJ12, iJ13,iJ21, iJ22,  iJ23, iJ31, iJ32, iJ33;
        long double  gL_new;

        nk     =  nk+1;
        gL_new = gamma_u(upartk, c2);

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){  
            vbar[i] = (upart[i] + upartk[i])/(gL_new + gL);
        }
        
        crossP(vbar,B,tmp);

        // Compute residual vector
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
            Fk[i] = upartk[i] - upart[i] - q*dt/mp * (E[i] + tmp[i]);
        }

         // Compute auxiliary coefficients
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            C1[i] = (gL_new + gL - (upartk[i]*(upartk[i] + upart[i])) / (gL_new*c2) )/ pow((gL + gL_new),2) ;
            C2[i] = -( upartk[i] / (gL_new*c2) )/ ((gL_new + gL),2) ;
        }

    
        // Compute Jacobian
          J11 = 1. - (q*dt/mp) * (C2[1] * (upartk[2] + upart[2]) * B[3] - C2[1] * (upartk[3] + upart[3]) * B[2]) ;
          J12 = - (q*dt/mp)*(C1[2] * B[3] - C2[2] * (upartk[3] + upart[3]) * B[2]) ;
          J13 = - (q*dt/mp) * (C2[3] * (upartk[2] + upart[2]) * B[3] - C1[3] * B[2]) ;
          J21 = - q*dt/mp * (- C1[1] * B[3] + C2[1] * (upartk[3] + upart[3]) * B[1]) ;
          J22 = 1. - q*dt/mp * (- C2[2] * (upartk[1] + upart[1]) * B[3] + C2[2] * (upartk[3] + upart[3]) * B[1]) ;
          J23 = - q*dt/mp * (- C2[3] * (upartk[1] + upart[1]) * B[3] + C1[3] * B[1]) ;
          J31 = - q*dt/mp * (C1[1] * B[2] - C2[1] * (upartk[2] + upart[2]) * B[1]) ;
          J32 = - q*dt/mp * (C2[2] * (upartk[1] + upart[1]) * B[2] - C1[2] * B[1]) ;
          J33 = 1. - q*dt/mp * (C2[3] * (upartk[1] + upart[1]) * B[2] - C2[3] * (upartk[2] + upart[2]) * B[1]) ;

          // Compute inverse Jacobian
           Det = J11*J22*J33 + J21*J32*J13 + J31*J12*J23 - J11*J32*J23 - J31*J22*J13 - J21*J12*J33;
           iJ11 = (J22*J33 - J23*J32) / Det ;
           iJ12 = (J13*J32 - J12*J33) / Det ;
           iJ13 = (J12*J23 - J13*J22) / Det ;
           iJ21 = (J23*J31 - J21*J33) / Det ;
           iJ22 = (J11*J33 - J13*J31) / Det ;
           iJ23 = (J13*J21 - J11*J23) / Det ;
           iJ31 = (J21*J32 - J22*J31) / Det ;
           iJ32 = (J12*J31 - J11*J32) / Det ;
           iJ33 = (J11*J22 - J12*J21) / Det ;

        // Compute new upartk = upartk - J^(-1) * F(upartk)
          dupartk[1] = - (iJ11 * Fk[1] + iJ12 * Fk[2] + iJ13 * Fk[3]);
          dupartk[2] = - (iJ21 * Fk[1] + iJ22 * Fk[2] + iJ23 * Fk[3]);
          dupartk[3] = - (iJ31 * Fk[1] + iJ32 * Fk[2] + iJ33 * Fk[3]);

        // Check convergence
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
          upartk[i] +=  dupartk[i] ;
        }
          abserr = sqrt(dotP(dupartk, dupartk));
    } while(abserr > tol && nk < nkmax); // End of while -> end of cycle

    // Update velocity 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        upart[i] = upartk[i];
    }
   
    
}
```

I am trying to run a code that contains this function and I am getting the "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated".

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong? I am not that familiar with the C syntax, have I declared a variable, matrix in the wrong way?

Comment: Use a *debugger* to catch it at run-time, to see when and where you go out of bounds of one of your arrays.

Comment: Please find the exact line where the message is given.

Comment: My guess is that it happens when you do `dupartk[3] = ...` as you seem to have forgotten that indexes are zero-based at that point.

Comment: There's also other mistakes in your code, like the division with `((gL_new + gL),2)`. There are probably more mistakes hiding in the code. You might want to enable a *lot* of extra warnings, and treat them as errors that needs to be fixed.

Comment: There is no `B[3]`. There are only `B[0]...B[2]`. Note that indexes go from 0...n-1.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to translate the code from Fortran and messed thing up!

Comment: @Jokerp Do not worry. Just throw this code into the trash can.:)

Comment: There's really one rule to follow when doing translations between languages, which are valid both for programming languages as well as written and spoken languages: Don't do literal translations. They almost never turn out well. For programming languages it's almost always better to reimplement the underlying algorithm instead, using the idioms and facilities available in the new language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix 1-based indexing and 0-based indexing. But C arrays use 0-based indexing.

At several positions you use `variable[3]`, where only `variable[2]` is allowed:

```
      dupartk[3] = - (iJ31 * Fk[1] + iJ32 * Fk[2] + iJ33 * Fk[3]);
//            ^                                               ^
```

Move all those indices by one and those accesses *there* be fine:

```
      dupartk[0] = - (iJ11 * Fk[0] + iJ12 * Fk[1] + iJ13 * Fk[2]);
      dupartk[1] = - (iJ21 * Fk[0] + iJ22 * Fk[1] + iJ23 * Fk[2]);
      dupartk[2] = - (iJ31 * Fk[0] + iJ32 * Fk[1] + iJ33 * Fk[2]);
```

But keep in mind that there are several other wrong indices, e.g. `B[3]` and `C[3]`. Check each index.

Answer (score 3):

The array indexes are from `zero` not `one`.

You write and read outside the bounds all of your arrays in your code.

You simply need to decrease all the indexes by `1`.